# Weird artifacts on blender workbench and evee 3D viewport (v 3.31 LTS)

Tags: 3d-view

anybody shared this issue? thank's

[image: Evee view]

[image: Workbench view]
[image: Normals orientation view]

@Gorgious : I've checked the normal see 2 last images

Comment: Your polygon normals look messed up.

Comment: @Gorgious : I've updagted original post to reply to you

Comment: Check for custom split normals under the Mesh tab in the properties editor (Green triangle icon) and remove them if there are any

Comment: There is no Split normal neither weighten normale modifier. For info in Cycle it s fine... this rocket is inserted from asset library and in the source file everything is perfect... thank you for your help. Maiby my blender file is corrupted...